# iOS App with different bundle names for locales

Tags: ios, localization, localizable.strings

So i'm following the instructions on the apple site to localize my app name:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html

I've created a InfoPlist.strings file for locales like en_GB.lproj etc... and set the CFBundleDisplayName appropriately.Everytime I build on the simulator using the appropriate locale I dont see the custom locale name on them. Does this only work for language like fr.lproj and not locales?

Comment: Actually yes. If you want to localize bundle display name you'll have to create a localized version of 'project'-info.plist. Easiest way to do this is trough 'file inspector' clicking '+' on localization tab.

Comment: Thanks, if I try this the plist file gets moved into its own .lproj folder and I get a compiler error saying it can't find the base plist file. I tried looking through the project settings but can't determine where I need to set this locale specific path. Should I really try to set this? If I have multiple locales do I need to set everyone of them ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it with Xcode 6. Add languages you need at your Project (not Target) page. For a country-specific language like en-GB you select 'Other' and choose the language `English (United Kingdom)` from a long list.

This will create the following files in Supporting Files directory:

Info.plist - an XML file containing keys and default values

InfoPlist.strings - a directory containing localized files for each language you've chosen, e.g.

```
InfoPlist.strings (Base)
InfoPlist.strings (English)
InfoPlist.strings (English (United Kingdom))
InfoPlist.strings (French)
```

Right click on `Info.plist` and select "Open as Source". Add the following lines:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
```

(The actual folder names will be en.lproj, en-GB.lproj, fr.lproj, but to create them manually you probably need to do it in Finder and then drag to Xcode, since Xcode creates only "virtual" folders, not the real ones)

Open `InfoPlist.strings` for a language other than default (e.g French) and add the following line:

```
CFBundleDisplayName="Nom de l\'app en Française";
```

(Notice the semicolon at end, otherwise the build will fail).
Rebuild your project.